# How to improve svm

Tags: python, svm, data-science

I apologize in advance for my bad English.

So, I'm working on my final year study project and the description says to make a state of the art on the methods often used to predict churn in telecommunications and then choose two methods that will be applied to the data.

It also says to try to add my contribution to one of the methods.

I chose the decision tree and SVM methods. I would like to add my contribution to the SVM method but I do not know how. I did some research and the most common thing is the "Cross-Validation" method but since it is used by everyone, is it considered a contribution?

I also thought about a hybridization but I'm not sure which algorithm would be best for that.

So I wanted to know if you could give me some ideas to explore in order to try to improve this algorithm, whether in precision, speed or otherwise.

If I sound like a beginner, that's because I am XD.

Answer (score 1):

I am also a beginner in this field , but i can give you some pointers i've come across,

1. You can look at newer feature generation(Try to do research on that fields specific to telecommunications)
2. Use different algorithm for imputation(KNN, central imputation).
3. If you want high accuracy go for XGBOOST .
4. As this is a churn problem i would concentrate on the recall.